# PHP Curl followlocation working from command line but not from browser

Tags: php, libcurl

I have written a small script to scrape some data from a website using cUrl in PHP. When curl is executed, there is a 301-redirect issued by the site which is taken care of by :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

However, when I run the same code from my browser, the redirect is NOT working.
Here is the complete curl request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $arr_params['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $arr_params['error_file']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
```

In the above code, $arr_params is set previously....

Comment: what is the output of this curl?

Comment: When I run this code on command line (SSH terminal), the page loads up....but when I run it through a browser, an HTTP 301 is issued. The url actually DOES redirect to another url..the redirect works on command line but not through a browser.

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5)` and see if that helps

Comment: That didn't help :( .....There has to be a reason for why curl redirects are working from the command line and not from the browser!

Comment: Do you get any warning from PHP when you run it from the browser (HTTP server)? Take a look at this: http://docs.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php#71313

Comment: Without knowing the URL you are curling, any params you are sending etc it's going to be hard to advise you in the best course for fixing it. There could be any number of things happening that are causing your issues with curl php, including but not limited to your environment setup. At least if we had the URL we could try to reproduce the issue